# SwingWorker not cancelling

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Conway's game of life game in java swing, and I need to operate a game loop in SwingWorker, and end the thread when The user decides to stop the loop from running. However, when I run the program, The UI freezes up, and I am forced to force quit the program. Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Here is my code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.*;
import java.awt.event.*; 
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.Timer;
// use swing timer for thread stuff
/**
 * Write a description of class GameLife here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class GameLife extends JPanel
{
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;
    private static final Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    private static final int w = (int)screen.getWidth();
    private static final int h = (int)screen.getHeight();
    private Color co1 = new Color(221,62,76);
    private Color co2 = new Color(0,200,235);
    private Color co3 = new Color(229,126,215);
    private int square = 20;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private double mousex;
    private double mousey;
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> selected;
    private boolean running = false;
    private GameWorker game;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GameLife
     */
    public GameLife()
    {
        game = new GameWorker();
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
             @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
                if(!running)
                {
                flag = true;
                mousex = me.getX();
                mousey = me.getY();
                repaint();
            }
            }
        });

                addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                int id = e.getID();
                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
                char space = ' ';
                if(id == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED)
                {

                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
                    {
                        running = !running;

                        if(running)
                        {
                            game.doInBackground();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            game.cancel(true);
                        }

                    }
                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_Q)
                    {
                     square+=5;

                     repaint();
                    }
                    if(keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_E)
                    {
                     square-=5;
                     repaint();
                    }

                }


            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);
        selected = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        mousex = 0;
        mousey = 0;


            }


    /**
     * An example of a method - replace this comment with your own
     *
     * @param  y  a sample parameter for a method
     * @return    the sum of x and y
     */

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
     super.paintComponent(g);
     Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
     g2.setColor(co1);
     g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

     for(int i = 0; i < square;i++)
        {
         for(int j = 0; j< square; j++)
         {
             g2.setColor(co1);
             g2.drawRect((w/square) *  j, (h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square));
             if(!(selected.contains(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square))))))
             {
             g2.setColor(co2);
             g2.fillRect((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square));
            }
            else
            {
             g2.setColor(co3);
             g2.fillRect((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square));
            }

            }
        }
        if(flag)
        {
         draw(g2, mousex, mousey);
         flag = false;
        }

    }


    public void draw(Graphics2D g, double x , double y)
    {
        int mx = (int) x;
        int my = (int) y;
        GameLife aiden = new GameLife();
        for(int i = 0; i < square;i++)
        {
         for(int j = 0; j< square; j++)
         {

             if( x > (w/square) * j && x < (w/square) * j + (w/square) && y > (h/square) * i && y < (h/square) * i + (h/square) && !(selected.contains(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square)))))) 
             {

                 selected.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square))));

                }
                else if( x > (w/square) * j && x < (w/square) * j + (w/square) && y > (h/square) * i && y < (h/square) * i + (h/square) && selected.contains(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square))))) 
             {

                selected.remove(new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList((w/square) * j,(h/square) * i,(w/square),(h/square))));

                }

            }
        }

        repaint();
    }

    public static void main()
    {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Conley's Game");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GameLife canvas = new GameLife();
          frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);
          canvas.setSize(w,h);
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Here is my SwingWorker Class

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
/**
 * Write a description of class GameWorker here.
 *
 * @author (your name)
 * @version (a version number or a date)
 */
public class GameWorker extends SwingWorker<Void,Void>
{


    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class GameWorker
     */
    public GameWorker()
    {


    }

    public Void doInBackground()
    {
      while(true)
      {
          System.out.println("hi");
          try{
             Thread.sleep(100);    
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {
             return null;   
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You shall not call `doInBackground()` yourself. If you do this then your current thread is executing the background work instead of a separate worker thread.. You should call `game.execute();`

Comment: Maybe try placing lines of code (`System.out.println();`) to signal if your code reached there before freezing.

Comment: When the `public void doInBackground()`, is called, it will never end, due to nothing being able to end the while loop.